# image quality loss when scaling down

Tags: image, libgdx

My image is 200px x 200px size. When I'm trying to draw it as 100px x 100px the image is being rendered awfull and unacceptable.

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBactch batch){
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0,100,100);
    batch.end();
}
```

When I'm drawin it like this:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBactch batch){
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

it has acceptable quality. Can i fix this and how? Below you can find screenshot from image rendering:

[image]

Comment: what is your img? Also if possible attach the screenshot. Scaling down is always connected to some loose of quality maybe it is just like it is?

Comment: @m.antkowicz tried to put a screenshot but it wont let me cuz i dont have 10 rep points so i uploaded the image here...
http://s21.postimg.org/ef5hmdul3/problem.png
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to apply your **Texture** [Linear TextureFilter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.TextureFilter.html#Linear)

```
    Texture texture = new Texture(... //creating your texture

    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear); //add this line

    Sprite img = new Sprite(texture);
```

Please notice that when you are scaling picture down there is always quality loose risk so you can still can be not satisfied with the result.

---

To get some information about TextureFilter and how to deal with them just read:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

Comment: well that turned out pretty acceptable... thank you sir!